# How can I this crypt/ decrypt flet app work correctly?

Tags: python

After working on a few projects, I decided to go back to my first project, read it and try to improve it. The original version is a simple code that encrypts or decrypts a message.

In the second version, I resolved the "empty spaces" issue. Next I'm trying to resolve the issue of "different letters" like "Ã". To make it work, I've created a function who's called once the char is not in the alphabet.

It converts the special letter into a "Code symbolic". The trouble happens when I've tried to decrypt.

Ex. Instead of replacing 'Á ', it adds it to the result, loop the letters and add it too. So :

'Á' become 'Á' and then become this : 'Áuuwony'

I'll paste the code bellow:

```
import flet as ft
import string
import pyperclip3 as pc
import pandas

shift = 6
alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
# a basic app made in flet


def main(page: ft.Page):

    output = ""
    # this should un mark one of the boxes. Ex. If I clicked cryp and then decryp, the cryp box should return false.

    def not_alpha(e, char):
        """ This should read the csv doc with two columns. One with the "especial letter" and other with the "correspondent
        It's receives char as parameter
        """
        doc = pandas.read_csv("html.csv")
        letter = []
        new_char = ""
        for i in doc["Letters"]:
                letter.append(i)
        not_letter = [] #create a list with the Letters column

        for i in doc["Simbols"]:
            not_letter.append(i)  #create a list with the Simbols column
        char_excetions = zip(letter, not_letter) #put it together

        for i in char_excetions: # verify each element look for the "especial letter"or "correspondent"
            if char == str(i[0]):
                new_char = str(i[1])
            elif char == str(i[1]):
                new_char = str(i[0])
        return new_char

    def crypto(e, text_to_use):
        """Crypto message """
        global shift
        cryp_word = ""
        if shift > 25:
            shift = shift % 25
        for char in text_to_use:
            if char in alphabet:
                char_index = alphabet.index(char)
                cryp_char_index = char_index + shift
                if cryp_char_index > 25:
                    cryp_char_index = cryp_char_index % 25
                cryp_word += alphabet[cryp_char_index]
            else:
                if char == " ":
                    cryp_word += char
                else:
                    new_char = not_alpha(e, char)
                    cryp_word += str(new_char)

        return cryp_word

    def decrypto(e, text_to_use):
        """Decypto message """
        global shift
        decrypt_word = ""
        for char in text_to_use:
            if char in alphabet:
                char_index = alphabet.index(char)
                cryp_char_index = char_index - shift
                if cryp_char_index > 25:
                    cryp_char_index = cryp_char_index % 25
                decrypt_word += alphabet[cryp_char_index]
            else:
                if char == " ":
                    decrypt_word += char
                else:
                    new_char = not_alpha(e, char)
                    decrypt_word += str(new_char)
        return decrypt_word

# will execute the action previously selected.
    def execute(e):
        """catch the input and make it works as selected"""

        text_to_use = list(text.value.lower())
        text.value = ""
        result = ""
        final_text.disabled = False
        if cryp.value and text_to_use:
            decryp.value = False
            result = crypto(e, text_to_use)
        if decryp.value and text_to_use:
            cryp.value = False
            result = decrypto(e, text_to_use)

        final_text.value = str(result)
        output = final_text.value
        page.update()

    def copy(e, *output):
        copied = pc.copy(output)
        print(copied)

    page.title = "O segredo de Cesar"
    page.horizontal_alignment = ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
    page.horizontal_alignment = ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
    page.vertical_alignment = ft.MainAxisAlignment.START
    welcome = ft.Text(" Seja bem-vindo!", text_align=ft.TextAlign.CENTER)
    cryp = ft.Checkbox(label="Criptografar", value=False)
    decryp = ft.Checkbox(label="Descriptografar", value=False)
    text = ft.TextField(label="mensagem", hint_text="Digite ou cole a mensagem aqui", text_align=ft.TextAlign.CENTER, multiline=True, min_lines=1, max_lines=6, border=0)
    button = ft.ElevatedButton(text="Start", on_click=execute)
    final_text = ft.TextField("", text_align=ft.TextAlign.CENTER, multiline=True, min_lines=1, max_lines=6, border=0, disabled=True)
    button_copy = ft.ElevatedButton(text="Copy", on_click=copy)


    page.add(
        ft.Row([welcome], alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER),
        ft.Row([decryp, cryp], alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER),
        ft.Row([text, button], alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER),
        ft.Row([final_text, button_copy], alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER)
    )


ft.app(target=main)
```

Here the char_exceptions's print:

```
(('Á', '&Aacute;'), ('É', '&Eacute;'), ('Í', '  &Iacute;'), ('Ó', '&Oacute;'), ('Ú', '&Uacute;'), ('á', ' &aacute;'), ('é', '&eacute;'), ('í', '&iacute;'), ('ó', '&oacute;'), ('ú', '&uacute;'), ('Â', '&Acirc;'), ('Ê', '&Ecirc;'), ('Ô', '&Ocirc;'), ('â', '&acirc;'), ('ê', ' &ecirc;'), ('ô', '&ocirc;'), ('À', ' &Agrave;'), ('à', '  &agrave;'), ('Ü', '&Uuml;'), ('ü', '&uuml;'), ('Ç', '&Ccedil;'), ('ç', '&ccedil;'), ('Ã', '&Atilde;'), ('Õ', '&Otilde;'), ('ã', '&atilde;'), ('õ', '&otilde;'), ('Ñ', '&Ntilde;'), ('ñ', '&Ntilde;'), ('&', '&gt&;'), ('“', '&gt";'), ('‘', "&gt';"), ('‘', "&gt';"), ('<', '&lt;'), ('>', '&gt;'))
```

I've tried to make the `cryp_word`  as f string, thinking that, if the separated character were the value of a variable, it would be possible to solve the problem in the opposite way.
i've tried add this:

```
crypted_word = f"{cryp_word}{new_char}" 
return crypted_word
```

the result the result doesn't show nothing after the special char

Also tried to create another variable with an f string. result shows nothing.

I haven't found a similar case yet that I could use as a base.

Have any of you experienced a similar problem?

Comment: You don't need any of the `str()` calls in `not_alpha`.  You also don't need the enormous pandas module just to read a simple data file.  "It doesn't work as expected" is not very helpful.  Exactly what does it do?

Comment: Your encoding process converts (for example) `Á` to `&Aacute`.  The decoding process does one character at a time, so you expand ampersand to `&amp`.  You need to look for the escape sequences as a whole word.

Comment: i've tried add this: crypted_word = f"{cryp_word}{new_char}"

        return crypted_word

Comment: the result the result  doesn't show nothing after the  special char. Also using the f string in cryp_word and nothing shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixes your handling of the HTML entities.  Note that the entities will be included in the ciphertext without encryption, so you'll see `&Aacute` in the output.  I removed all of the flet and pandas stuff, so you'll need to incorporate that back again.

Note that I added a `nextchar` generator which returns the next "character" from the string; if it finds an ampersand, it grabs everything up to the semicolon.

```
import string

shift = 6
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

def read_exceptions():
    dct = {}
    for row in open('html.csv'):
        a,b = row.strip().split(',')
        dct[a] = b
        dct[b] = a
    return dct

def nextchar(s):
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        if s[i] == '&':
            j = s.find(';',i)
            yield s[i:j+1]
            i = j+1
        else:
            yield s[i]
            i += 1

def main():
    char_exceptions = read_exceptions()

    def not_alpha(e,char):
        return char_exceptions.get(char,char)

    def crypto(e, text_to_use):
        """Crypto message shift+ """
        cryp_word = ""
        for char in text_to_use:
            if char in alphabet:
                char_index = alphabet.index(char)
                cryp_char_index = char_index + shift
                if cryp_char_index > 25:
                    cryp_char_index = cryp_char_index % 25
                cryp_word += alphabet[cryp_char_index]
            elif char == " ":
                cryp_word += char
            else:
                cryp_word += not_alpha(e, char)
        return cryp_word

    def decrypto(e, text_to_use):
        """Decypto message shift - """
        decrypt_word = ""
        for char in nextchar(text_to_use):
            if char in alphabet:
                char_index = alphabet.index(char)
                cryp_char_index = char_index - shift
                if cryp_char_index > 25:
                    cryp_char_index = cryp_char_index % 25
                decrypt_word += alphabet[cryp_char_index]
            elif char == " ": # blank space case
                decrypt_word += char
            else:
                decrypt_word += not_alpha(e, char)
        return decrypt_word

#    def execute(e):
#        """catch the input and make it works as selected"""
#
#        text_to_use = text.value.lower()
#        text.value = ""
#        result = ""
#        final_text.disabled = False
#        if cryp.value and text_to_use:
#            decryp.value = False
#            result = crypto(e, text_to_use)
#        if decryp.value and text_to_use:
#            cryp.value = False
#            result = decrypto(e, text_to_use)
#
#        final_text.value = str(result)
#        output = final_text.value

    x = crypto(0,'abcÍde')
    print(x)
    y = decrypto(0,x)
    print(y)

main()
```

Output:

```
ghi&Iacute;jk
abcÍde
```